# Removing Special character when importing data from excel

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm importing data from excel to data table. It's working fine. But in some fields, data imported with unknown character '�'. But excel doesn't have such character. Here is my code.

I have tried in many ways. This is my final code.

`$new_prod_desc = (ucfirst($data[0])." ".ucfirst($data[5])." ".ucfirst($data[1])." ".ucfirst($data[2]));
$new_prod_desc = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$new_prod_desc);`

Thanks.

Comment: In order to get a proper fix, you'll have to find out what encodings are used in Excel and your database table.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a single byte character, but a UTF-8 sequence `ef bf bd`:

From [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280):

```
U+FFFD  �   ef bf bd    REPLACEMENT CHARACTER
```

Maybe it is replacing an even worse character?

If you just want it to vanish, you could search and replace the byte sequence.

Comment: when to replace these chars? Before utf8_decode or after utf8_decode? and also which one i want to replace? 'ef bf bd' or 'U+FFFD'?

Comment: @Devpower:  I would not use `utf8_decode()` at all, especially if you are not now and all you get is these troublesome characters.

Comment: I understood. Pls tell me which one i want to replace? 'ef bf bd' or 'U+FFFD'?

Comment: I found the character. that is 'Ù'. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

First verify that the excel document is in UTF-8 code.

Try to add the function

> utf8_decode

like this:

```
$new_prod_desc = utf8_decode($new_prod_desc);
```

Comment: That function generates `ISO-8859-1`. It'll ruin data unless the database uses `ISO-8859-1`.